# vcvarsall.bat missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am using Windows 10 64bit. Python 3.5.5 with Visual Studio Community 2017(installed recently). (I had earlier uninstalled visual studio community 2015 before installing 2017).

I am trying to follow the procedure [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md).

I was trying to install coco api and i used git to clone the directly and changed directory to cocoapi/PythonAPI.

When i run **make** i get this error.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I looked through stackoverflow and found that i needed to install Common tools for Visual C++ for Visual Studio. When i looked up the info on python,

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 12 2018, 17:44:09) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

And MSC v.1900 corresponds to VS 2015 and i uninstalled that to install VS 17.

So, is there a way to get vcvarsall.bat work with VS Community 2017 or do i have to uninstall 2017 and reinstall 2015? Also i tried installing 2015 with 2017 present, but it is blocking my installation as there is a newer version installed.

Comment: I can't speak for your specific build, but VC 2017 does have a vcvarsall.bat, just perhaps in a different location from previous versions.  For example, try `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat`

Comment: Thanks! I did find this earlier but i am unable to redirect pycocotools installation to use this batch file. I tried copying this into VS 2014 but it still is not reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to uninstall previous versions and reinstall Visual Studio 2017 from scratch. It helped solve the issue.